# Redis as service on CentOs6

Tags: centos, redis

I've been trying to get redis to run as a service on a CentOS 6 server but I cant get the startup script to work properly.

the startup script distributed with redis does not support chkconfig so I found another on github at https://gist.github.com/tahajahangir/155176867afed0ff80ad however lines 36 & 37:

```
chown ${REDIS_USER-redis}:${REDIS_USER-redis} /var/run/redis
daemon --user ${REDIS_USER-redis} "$redis $REDIS_CONF_FILE $REDIS_OPTIONS"
```

give errors when I run `service redis-server start`.
I solved the first error about incorrect username `redis` by changing line 36 to

```
chown root:root /var/run/redis
```

but I still have the remaining error:

```
/usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `.pid'
Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
```

I've tried several things but I'm not entirely sure where this "extra" `.pid` is coming from.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: In the last comment on the page you posted should be the solution to your problem.You have to change line 37 to: `daemon --user ${REDIS_USER-redis} --pidfile ${pidfile} "$redis $REDIS_CONF_FILE $REDIS_OPTIONS"`

Comment: Many thanks, I had actually tried the --pid part at the *end* of the line but that had no effect, adding it before the other path options seems to do the trick. If youd like to make your comment an answwer Ill accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last comment on the page you posted should be the solution to your problem.You have to change line 37 to:

> daemon --user ${REDIS_USER-redis} --pidfile ${pidfile} "$redis
>   $REDIS_CONF_FILE $REDIS_OPTIONS"

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a packaged version of redis, which will work as soon as you install it.  For CentOS 6, EPEL has redis 2.4.10.  You can also get the latest 2.8 and 3.0 versions of redis from the [IUS project](https://ius.io).